# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor possible memory leak

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have my application running on Docker. It starts using around 80MB of memory. In three days it reaches around 300MB. The application runs  every 30 minutes and retrieves data from a database in JSON format. There are not streams or hash maps. on VisualVM only Live threads increase.  On memory sampler, Object[], char[] and String increases for some time but decrease afterwards. I am not sure where to start to really find the problem. VisualVM shows memory size around 120-140 all the time.

That's my thread:

```
final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    Runnable lastUpdates = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            Date date = new Date();
            System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));                
            dynamoDbCon.getData();
        }
    };

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskLastUpdates, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: If you constrain the application to for example 100mb, is it working fine? If you give 'infinite' resources to application, it will use as much as it can since it's faster that way. Now if you limit the memory, the GC will start to work and release memory for unused objects to make space for new ones.

Comment: I tried using argument -Xms but it didn't work. VisualVM shows everything ok running on PC but it crashes after a few days on Docker due to the memory.